# How to delete symbolic link when source is deleted?

Tags: c#, .net

My program makes symbolic links from a destination `D:\source`.
Symbolic links are made in `D:\Destination`.

When I delete from the source folder, how can I then delete the symbolic link in the destination folder?

My program runs on an interval, so it scans the source and makes symbolic links.  So I guess it should delete upon a scan?

Comment: What method do you use to create the symlinks?

Comment: [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);
    static int SYMLINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY = 1;                                         CreateSymbolicLink(symD, targetD, SYMLINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY);

Comment: According to [How to remove a symbolic link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-to-remove-a-symbolic-link/e171f76a-a62b-4604-8777-3439492bf1f7), you should be able to simply call the DeleteFile function, or the RemoveDirectory function.